# filtering CKEditor HTML attributes

Tags: html, ckeditor, filtering

I've found many posts about filtering complete HTML tags when CKEditor submits data (eg: stripping SCRIPT, STYLE, etc).  What I need to filter is particular attributes, but leave the original tag.

For example, I'm fine if a user submits data that has a P, DIV or SPAN tag, but if they submit a P, DIV or SPAN that has a STYLE attribute, I need to remove the STYLE attribute.

I can't seem to find this, but open to anyone who has insight.

Comment: So you're doing this on the server? Which technology are you using?

Answer (score 4):

There are two solutions for your problem:

1. (recommended) [Advanced Content Filter (ACF)](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) (since 4.1):

   ```
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
       allowedContent: 'span div p[id,class]; h1 a img hr table tr td ul ol li[*]{*}(*)'
   } );
   ```

   With ACF you can **precisely** specify which tags, which attributes, classes and styles will be accepted (produced) by your editor. See [more about the rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules). Also download the latest 4.1 build and play with official Advanced Content Filter sample.
2. The second option is `dataProcessor` (3.x, 4.x):

   ```
   editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( {
       elements: {
           $: function( element ) { // you can specify p, div etc. here instead of $ (wildcard)
               if ( element.attributes.style ) {
                    console.log( 'Nuke style attr on' element );
                    delete element.attributes.style;
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem, the allowed elements are split by ";", space or comma does not work.

Comment: @Kevin Right. You can also use the [object format](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-3) to avoid bugs.